# Email server not working with external emails (like Google, Yahoo)

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, mx-record, gmail

I have setup Modoboa server in Ubuntu system (static IP) using [this link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/email-server-ubuntu-18-04-modoboa).

Internal emails are working (**username@example.com** to **username2@example.com**), but an email from an external provider like Google or Yahoo is not working.

Already set up with A, MX (Google, MailServer), TXT (spf and _dmarc) records, but still emails from external providers are not delivered.

I'm getting this error in `/var/log/mail.log`:

> (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.146.27]:25: Connection timed out)

Also, port 25 is open.

I got the updates from the Internet Service Provider.  Port 25 is blocked by them.

What is the alternative way to start. (Google, Yahoo mail)

Comment: There are three alternatives: 1) ask the current provider to open the port as you are hosting a mail server 2) change the service provider to one that allows it 3) hire someone with the required expertise to host an email server. Frankly, someone asking this question should not be allowed to use port 25 freely. We have seen so many poorly configured servers as *open relays* etc.

Comment: I mostly agree with @EsaJokinen, but I understand that people have to learn it somewhere. One more option may be a VPN with some port forwarding from the other endpoint or use a cheap VM. Also, hosting email anywhere outside of a collocation/cloud without a backup server for anything but experimenting is not a good idea.